# Is there way to create tuple from list(without codegeneration)?

Tags: scala, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Sometimes there are needs to create tuples from small collections(for example scalding framework).

```
def toTuple(list:List[Any]):scala.Product = ...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't know the arity up front and want to do a terrible terrible hack, you can do this:

```
def toTuple[A <: Object](as:List[A]):Product = {
  val tupleClass = Class.forName("scala.Tuple" + as.size)
  tupleClass.getConstructors.apply(0).newInstance(as:_*).asInstanceOf[Product]
}
toTuple: [A <: java.lang.Object](as: List[A])Product

scala> toTuple(List("hello", "world"))
res15: Product = (hello,world)
```

Comment: +1 Very useful for cleaning up assignment from strings. It doesn't work for var (a, b, c) = toTuple(myIter.toList) - Any ideas?

Comment: Rubistro: for that purpose you can use `var List(a,b,c) = myIter.toList`

Answer (score 15):

You really don't want your method to return `Product` since this is uselessly vague.  If you want to be able to use the returned object as a tuple, then you'll have to know its arity.  So what you can do is have a series of `toTupleN` methods for different arities.  For convenience, you can add these as implicit methods on `Seq`.

How about this:

```
class EnrichedWithToTuple[A](elements: Seq[A]) {
  def toTuple2 = elements match { case Seq(a, b) => (a, b) }
  def toTuple3 = elements match { case Seq(a, b, c) => (a, b, c) }
  def toTuple4 = elements match { case Seq(a, b, c, d) => (a, b, c, d) }
  def toTuple5 = elements match { case Seq(a, b, c, d, e) => (a, b, c, d, e) }
}
implicit def enrichWithToTuple[A](elements: Seq[A]) = new EnrichedWithToTuple(elements)
```

and use it like:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).toTuple3
res0: (Int, Int, Int) = (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Alternately, if you are expecting tuples of a single arity, you can just write out `exampleList match { case Seq(a, b, c) => (a, b, c)}`

Answer (score 14):

If, as @dhg observed, you know the expected arity up front you can do something useful here. Using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) you could write,

```
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> import Traversables._
import Traversables._

scala> import Tuples._
import Tuples._

scala> List(1, 2, 3).toHList[Int :: Int :: Int :: HNil] map tupled
res0: Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = Some((1,2,3))
```

Comment: But `Shapeless` doesn't provide the way to create a `Tuple` from `List` if length of list is undefined in compile time, it can lead to runtime errors

Answer (score 5):

Do you want a `Tuple` or just a `Product`. Because for the latter:

```
case class SeqProduct[A](elems: A*) {
  override def productArity: Int = elems.size
  override def productElement(i: Int) = elems(i)
}

SeqProduct(List(1, 2, 3): _*)
```

Comment: Also wishing for `Tuple`, so I could use `FunctionX.tupled`, which indeed requires a `TupleX`, not `Product` (note even `ProductX`).

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Kim Stebel's idea, I wrote a simple utility that creates tuple from seq.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor

/**
 * Created by Bowen Cai on 1/24/2015.
 */
sealed trait Product0 extends Any with Product {

  def productArity = 0
  def productElement(n: Int) = throw new IllegalStateException("No element")
  def canEqual(that: Any) = false
}
object Tuple0 extends Product0 {
  override def toString() = "()"
}

case class SeqProduct(elems: Any*) extends Product {
  override def productArity: Int = elems.size
  override def productElement(i: Int) = elems(i)
  override def toString() = elems.addString(new StringBuilder(elems.size * 8 + 10), "(" , ",", ")").toString()
}

object Tuples {

  private[this] val ctors = {
    val ab = Array.newBuilder[Constructor[_]]
    for (i <- 1 to 22) {
      val tupleClass = Class.forName("scala.Tuple" + i)
      ab += tupleClass.getConstructors.apply(0)
    }
    ab.result()
  }

  def toTuple(elems: Seq[AnyRef]): Product = elems.length match {
    case 0 => Tuple0
    case size if size <= 22 =>
      ctors(size - 1).newInstance(elems: _*).asInstanceOf[Product]
    case size if size > 22 => new SeqProduct(elems: _*)
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, @xKommando.  This is just what I needed. Because I wanted _toTuple_ to apply to a sequence of _Any_ rather than _AnyRef_, I replaced the type of elems with _Seq[Any]_ and replaced the expression for the case `size<=22` with `val refs = for (e <- elems) yield e.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
      ctors(size - 1).newInstance(refs: _*).asInstanceOf[Product]` (based on the answer here: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751484/scala-how-to-force-wrapping-an-integer-as-an-object))

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val numbers = Seq(1,2,4)
numbers: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 4)

scala> val string = numbers.mkString("(",",",")")
string: String = (1,2,4)

*** mkString(start:String, sep: String, end: String)
```

I have generated it in my where-in-clause.