# Scala: How to force wrapping an integer as an object?

Tags: scala, object, int

I am getting an error here:

```
val a: Int = 1
val i: Int with Object = a
```

How can I convert this 1 to an integer object in scala?
My purpose is to pass it to an `Array[Int with Object]`.
It currently displays the error:

```
error type mismatch
found : Int(1)
required: Int with java.lang.Object
       val i: Int with Object = a
                                ^
```

**EDIT**

I have this error because I am using an android [`ArrayAdapter`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) from scala, and therefore by defining:

```
class ImageAdapter[T](ctx: Context, viewResourceId: Int, pointers: Array[T]) extends ArrayAdapter[T](ctx, viewResourceId, pointers) { ... }
```

it throws me this error:

```
overloaded method constructor ArrayAdapter with alternatives: 
(android.content.Context,Int,java.util.List[T])android.widget.ArrayAdapter[T] <and> 
(android.content.Context,Int,Array[T with Object])android.widget.ArrayAdapter[T] <and> 
(android.content.Context,Int,Int)android.widget.ArrayAdapter[T]
   cannot be applied to (android.content.Context,  Int, Array[T])
```

So I need to replace `T` with `T <: Object` in `class ImageAdapter[T <: Object](ctx: ...`

Comment: Object isn't a trait - what does `Int with Object` even mean?

Comment: I'm using the Android `ArrayAdapter` class, and from scala it requires something of type `Array[T with Object]`. From Java it requires a `java.lang.Object[]`.

Comment: Can you show us your actual code so we can understand how you end up with the `Array[T with Object]` type?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`Int` is a scala type which usually maps to java's `int`, but will map to `java.lang.Integer` when boxed. Whether it's boxed or not is mostly transparent in scala.

In any case, `Int` is definitely not a sub-type of `java.lang.Object`. In fact `Int` is a sub-type of `AnyVal` which is not a sub-type of `java.lang.Object`. Thus `Int with Object` is pretty much nonsensical, given that you cannot have any concrete type that is both an `Int` and a `java.lang.Object`.

I think what you meant is rather something like:

```
val i: Object = a
```

Or more idomatically:

```
val i: AnyRef = a
```

Of course, none of this compiles, but you can force the boxing of the `Int` value by casting to `AnyRef`:

```
val i: AnyRef = a.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
```

Unlike in the general case, casting an `AnyVal` to an `AnyRef` is always safe, and will force the boxing.

You can also use the more specific `Int.box` function:

```
val i: AnyRef = Int.box(a)
```