# Find the arity of a Product type, without an instance

Tags: scala

I want to define a function that is parameterized by a generic Product type, but which can work out the Product's arity. Here's an example snippet. I'd like to do the arity check when f(…) is invoked, rather than when f(…)() is invoked. How can I do this?

```
def f[T<:Product](names:Seq[String], values:()=>T) = {
  () => {
    val x = values()
    if (x.productArity != names.size) scala.sys.error("Size mismatch")
    names.zip(x.productIterator.map(_.toString).toSeq).map(kv => kv._1+"="+kv._2)
  }
}
```

(This is a pretty useless function, just for demonstration. The important points are (1) it is parameterized by a Product type, (2) the function only makes sense if the arity of the product matches a certain value which is known when I invoke the function, (3) it's expensive/impossible for me to obtain an instance of the Product when I invoke the function. My actual use case is a utility class for writing out SQL statements, based on a spark RDD.)

If necessary, I could write out a whole family of functions, one for each size of Tuple. But that feels nasty, and I'm hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit better than writing different methods can be found using type classes:

```
case class Arity[P]( get: Int )

object Arity {
  def apply[P]( implicit arity: Arity[P] ) = arity
  implicit def tuple2[A,B] = Arity[(A,B)]( 2 )
  implicit def tuple3[A,B,C] = Arity[(A,B,C)]( 3 )
  //...
} 

def f[T<:Product:Arity](names:Seq[String], values:()=>T) = {
  () => {
    val x = values()
    if ( Arity[T].get != names.size) scala.sys.error("Size mismatch")
    names.zip(x.productIterator.map(_.toString).toSeq).map(kv => kv._1+"="+kv._2)
  }
}
```

Of course, you will need to write down `Arity` objects for all possible tuple sizes. You can automatize this using code generation or (if you are daring and patient) using macros.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define `names` as a `Product` of the same subtype:

```
def f[T<:Product](names: T, values:()=>T) = {
  () => {
    val x = values()
    names.productIterator.toList.zip(x.productIterator.map(_.toString).toSeq).map(kv => kv._1+"="+kv._2)
  }
}

scala> f(("one", "two"), () => ("1", "2"))()
res15: List[java.lang.String] = List(one=1, two=2)

scala> f(("one", "two"), () => ("1"))()
<console>:9: error: inferred type arguments [java.io.Serializable] do not conform to method f's type parameter bounds [T <: Product]
              f(("one", "two"), () => ("1"))()
              ^

scala> f(("one"), () => ("1", "2"))()
<console>:9: error: inferred type arguments [java.io.Serializable] do not conform to method f's type parameter bounds [T <: Product]
              f(("one"), () => ("1", "2"))()
              ^
```

Of course it makes it inconvenient to pass in names if you have them in some sort of collection. You can use one of these methods to convert from `List` to `Tuple` for example: [Is there way to create tuple from list(without codegeneration)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305290/is-there-way-to-create-tuple-from-listwithout-codegeneration).

Maybe using `HList` instead of `Product` is not a bad idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using reflection which will work for Products 1-22:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def tupleArity(typ: Type): Int = {
    for(i <- 2 to 22) {
      if (typ.member(stringToTermName("_" + i)) == NoSymbol) return i - 1
    }
    22
}
```

Minimal example:

```
def f[T <: Product](implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Int = tupleArity(typeOf[T])

scala> f[Tuple2[_, _]]
res18: Int = 2
```